# Extracting Attachment Data from SalesForce, If Attachement ID's are given in hundreds

Tags: salesforce-id, salesforce2salesforce

I have a list of Attachment ID's with me given by the client, I want to extract the Attachment-Data with the given ID's(provided by client). How can i do this...is there any tool or app in SF through which i can get the attachment data for the only ID's I have. As through data-loader it is not possible as per me.

Please provide some solution to this ASAP.

Thanks 
Chirag

Answer (score 2):

Dataloader is the best tool to Migrate or get the attachments from salesforce. In case this is not possible. you can try appexchange tools like 
[FileExporter](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iz0jEAC)

you can find more details in this Link: http://www.madronasg.com/blog/how-migrate-attachments-one-salesforcecom-org-another#.UiVRejanog1

Comment: The thing is, through DataLoader I am only able to extract the Attachments details in .csv format, I want the actual data-files also along with that.
I have tried FileExporter App, but i am not able to configure it properly. The error:                                            
EXTRACTING DOCUMENT BODIES...
EXTRACTING DOCUMENT FOLDER IDS...
EXTRACTING DOCUMENT NAMES...
EXTRACTING DOCUMENT TYPES...
CREATING DOCUMENT FILES...
E:\FileExporter\Step3d-ReadBody.vbs(26, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found
The system cannot find the file CSVs\Document.Type.csv.
can u help me in this !

Comment: </br>
Could you help me with configuring FileExporter ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a tool like **Data Loader** Available in *Enterprise, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com* editions. In this case, while exporting the data you would be required to tweak the SOQL query in such a way that it returns Attachments only related to that ID, but not all of it. When you see the Attachment object, one of the field in that is parentid which is nothing but the id of the related Parent Account. So you would have to filter the records on that criteria.

For ex:

```
SELECT id, parentid FROM Attachment WHERE parentid='00P28000000nPco'
```

The above query would return files only attached to this particular solution. I have used one in this query. You can modify the query as per your requirement and then export data.